# Jenkins does not execute any command no matter how basic it is, both with shell and with windows

Tags: java, jenkins, cmd

[image]

When executing the following command `DATE ​​/T`, it gives me the following output.

```
Lanzada por el usuario ignacio ariel marengo
Running as SYSTEM
Ejecutando.en el espacio de trabajo C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\prueba1
FATAL: la ejecución del comando ha fallado
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:523)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:470)
    at hudson.tools.ZipExtractionInstaller.performInstallation(ZipExtractionInstaller.java:83)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:70)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:221)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:150)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:342)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2433)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:955)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:128)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:92)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:816)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:524)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1899)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Build step 'Ejecutar un comando de Windows' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried many ways, but none work for me, I don't know what else I can do.

I have the server upstairs, the configurations are the basic ones, and there isn't much else.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your Job run a with a component which will be installed automatically (Maybe Java).

And your Jenkins instance could not download the artifact. I would check the tools configuration and Job configuration.

For more help show us more information.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, it was pointing to java from a wrong url in the settings, so I removed the url and installed java 11 on my pc, thus letting jenkins search the machine on its own.
Thank you very much!!